# Recording all broker transactions in ActiveMQ

Tags: logging, activemq

I would like to record all transactions that happen in ActiveMQ. When someone writes to a queue or reads from it, I would like to log that. Is there a way to turn on this kind of logging, or is there a data store somewhere which I can parse and read?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable DEBUG level logging in the .properties file for log4j.  You can find more details about how to change it here:

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-change-the-logging.html